# Pregunta sobre R usando JSONlite package

Tags: r

Tengo este archivo JSON:

```
[
    {
      "namespace": "drugs",
      "predicate": "alkaloids-and-derivatives",
      "entry": [
        {
          "value": "ajmaline-sarpagine-alkaloids",
          "expanded": "Ajmaline-sarpagine alkaloids"
        },
        {
          "value": "amaryllidaceae alkaloids",
          "expanded": "Amaryllidaceae alkaloids"
        }]
    }
]
```

Y quiero cambiarlo a este formato ***usando R y el JSONlite package, o cualquier otro paquete de R.***

```
[
    {
      "namespace": "drugs",
      "predicate": "alkaloids-and-derivatives",
      "value": "ajmaline-sarpagine-alkaloids",
      "expanded": "Ajmaline-sarpagine alkaloids"
    },
    {
      "namespace": "drugs",
      "predicate": "alkaloids-and-derivatives",
      "value": "amaryllidaceae alkaloids",
      "expanded": "Amaryllidaceae alkaloids"
    }
]
```

He leído que usando R y JSONlite package puedo cambiarlo.

Pero, no entiendo lo q hay que hacer.

Puede alguien ayudarme? Muchas gracias!

Intenté con lo siguiente:

```
NEWdf <- fromJSON("MIarchivoJSON")
View(NEWdf)

json4 <- flatten(NEWdf, recursive = TRUE)
FLATTENdf <- as.data.frame(json4)
View(FLATTENdf)
```

También probé con:

```
data <- fromJSON("MIarchivoJSON", flatten = TRUE)
```

Pero, tampoco funcionó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma muy simple usando las funciones que brinda `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

JSON_STR <- '[
    {
      "namespace": "drugs",
      "predicate": "alkaloids-and-derivatives",
      "entry": [
        {
          "value": "ajmaline-sarpagine-alkaloids",
          "expanded": "Ajmaline-sarpagine alkaloids"
        },
        {
          "value": "amaryllidaceae alkaloids",
          "expanded": "Amaryllidaceae alkaloids"
        }]
    }
]'

JSON_STR %>% 
  fromJSON(simplifyDataFrame = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(entry = as.list(entry)) %>% 
  unnest(entry)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  namespace predicate                 value                        expanded                
  <chr>     <chr>                     <chr>                        <chr>                   
1 drugs     alkaloids-and-derivatives ajmaline-sarpagine-alkaloids Ajmaline-sarpagine alka~
2 drugs     alkaloids-and-derivatives amaryllidaceae alkaloids     Amaryllidaceae alkaloids
```

Comentarios:

- Con `fromJSON(j, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)` logramos que `namespace` y `predicate` sean columnas del `data.frame` generado
- Con `mutate(entry = as.list(entry))` convertimos cada `entry` en una lista
- Finalmente con `unnest(entry)` "descomprimimos" la lista en múltiples filas

Comment: Genial la forma en que lo haces! Te agradezco mucho!

Comment: Cuando corrí tu código, obtuve el error "Error in isTRUE(simplifyVector) : object 'j' not found"

Comment: Sin embargo, trabajó muy bien cuando borré la j junto con la coma.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, había olvidado borrar la cadena de la llamada cuando pasé a usar el pipe.

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente codigo puede ayudarte. Al revisar la estructura de los datos en `R`, notamos que es una lista de tres elementos que a sus vez son de tispo lista.  Usamos la función `lapply` para recorrer la lista `entry` y convinar cada uno de sus elementos con los primeros elementos de la lista principal. Te recomiento revisar como usar listas en R ya que cuando trabajas con json en este lenguaje se tranfromarn a listas. Puedes empezar revizando `?list` y `?lapply` desde la consola.

```
#Cargamos la libreria 
library(jsonlite)

#Leemos el arcivo json desde un archivo guardado
jf<-read_json(path = "data/MiarchivoJSON.json")

#Observamos la estructura de jf
str(jf)

#Usamo lapply para tranformar jf
aux <- lapply(jf[[1]]$entry,function(x){
    c(jf[[1]][1:2],x)
})

#Observamos la estructura de aux
str(aux)

#Pasamos a Json de nuevo
toJSON(aux, pretty = TRUE)
[
  {
    "namespace": ["drugs"],
    "predicate": ["alkaloids-and-derivatives"],
    "value": ["ajmaline-sarpagine-alkaloids"],
    "expanded": ["Ajmaline-sarpagine alkaloids"]
  },
  {
    "namespace": ["drugs"],
    "predicate": ["alkaloids-and-derivatives"],
    "value": ["amaryllidaceae alkaloids"],
    "expanded": ["Amaryllidaceae alkaloids"]
  }
]
```

Observe que esta parte del `json` final  `"namespace": ["drugs"]` no es igual a lo que dejas en tu ejemplo `"namespace": "drugs"`. Algunas veces esto no causa conflico para su uso, comentame si en tu caso en necesario eliminar los corchetes. Revisare una forma de hacerlo con `jsonlite` por ahora los podes eliminar con `gsub`

```
#Pasamos a Json de nuevo
jft<-toJSON(aux, pretty = TRUE)

#Eliminamos los corchetes
jft<-gsub("\\[\"", "\"", jft)
jft<-gsub("\"\\]", "\"", jft)

#Imprimimos jft
jft
[
  {
    "namespace": "drugs",
    "predicate": "alkaloids-and-derivatives",
    "value": "ajmaline-sarpagine-alkaloids",
    "expanded": "Ajmaline-sarpagine alkaloids"
  },
  {
    "namespace": "drugs",
    "predicate": "alkaloids-and-derivatives",
    "value": "amaryllidaceae alkaloids",
    "expanded": "Amaryllidaceae alkaloids"
  }
]
```

Otra forma de leer los datos

```
#Tambien lo podemos leer desde la consola 
MiarchivoJSON <-'[
    {
      "namespace": "drugs",
      "predicate": "alkaloids-and-derivatives",
      "entry": [
        {
          "value": "ajmaline-sarpagine-alkaloids",
          "expanded": "Ajmaline-sarpagine alkaloids"
        },
        {
          "value": "amaryllidaceae alkaloids",
          "expanded": "Amaryllidaceae alkaloids"
        }]
    }
]'

jf2<- fromJSON(
 txt= MiarchivoJSON
)
```

Comment: Fantástica respuesta! Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Podrías explicar tu lógica detrás de aux <- lapply(jf[[1]]$entry,function(x){
    c(jf[[1]][1:2],x)
})

Comment: lapply es un misterio para mí.

Comment: Tampoco me queda claro como aplicar tu método si "entry" tiene un número variable de elementos en lugar de 2 elementos.

Comment: `lapply` toma dos argumentos una lista y una función. Entonces crea una especie de `loop` donde intera sobre cada uno de los elementos de la lista aplicándoles la función que usamos. En ese caso la lista que usamos es `entry`, luego pues en cada iteración cada elemento de `entry` ahora se llama x de tal manera que la función que le pasamos a l`apply` es simplemente una combinación de los elementos de la lista original con x. Al final `lapply` devuelve el resultado de cada iteración dentro de una lista.

Comment: No debe haber ningún problema cuando `entry` tenga mas de dos elementos. Donde podrías perder elementes es en el caso donde `entry` tenga mas "compañeros", bueno con esto me refiero a elementos al nivel de `namespace` y `predicate`. En ese caso en la función que convine `c(jf[[1]][1:2],x)`tendrías que pasar los índices de los compañeros adicionales donde figura **1:2**. Asi por ejemplo si entry tubiera 3 compañeros anteriores la función seria `c(jf[[1]][1:3],x)`